# DeRham Cohomology group

Tags: homology-cohomology

How can we show that given the manifold $M=\mathbb{S}^2$ and $U=\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{A\}$ and $V=\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \{B\}$, then:

$$H_{dR}^1(U)\oplus H_{dR}^1(V)\rightarrow H_{dR}^1(U\cap V) $$ cannot be surjective. The reasoning in my book says that $ H_{dR}^1(U)=H_{dR}^1(V)=\{[0]\}$ and $H_{dR}^1(\mathbb{S}^1)=H_{dR}^1(U\cap V)=\mathbb{R}$, hence they cannot be surjective. But I am having trouble seeing why this is the case, as in why the above is equal to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{[0]\}$.

Can anyone help me understand my confusion? Thank You

Comment: Note that $U, V$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ and $U\cap V$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: @I am sorry I might need alittle more than this.

Comment: Um.... do you know what is $H^1_{dR} (\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: I know the theorem on diffeomorphic invariance of $H_{dR}^k$, and the Poincare's Lemma,  $H_{dR}^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ are all exact closed 1-forms on $\mathbb{R}^2? $ which is $\{[0]\}$?

Comment: Poincare lemma tells you that all closed forms in $\mathbb R^2$ are exact, so $H^1_{dR}(\mathbb R^2) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Ok in my book it says for any start shaped open set $U \in \mathbb{R}^n $, we have $ H_{dR}^1(U)=\{[0]\},$ so if $H_{dR}^1( \mathbb{R}^2)=\{[0]\}$, then is $\mathbb{R}^2$ a star shaped open set in $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Comment: Well, is $\mathbb R^2$ a star-shaped open subset in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: That is what I am confused about the result seems like it is, but I do not know why it is.

Comment: Can you state the definition of a star-shaped subset?

Comment: Ok nvm it is a star shaped, but then it raises the next question how can you see that it is diffeomorphic to $U$ and $ V$ because this doesnt seem obvious. and this part is the real confusing part for me; $H^1_{dR}(U∩V)=ℝ $ I do not see how we can have this part to hold.

Comment: Do you know [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)?

Comment: Yes I have learned that in complex analysis.

Comment: That's exactly a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb S^2\setminus\{N\}$.

Comment: Hmm ok I will try to see how that holds, but how about $H^1_{dR}(U∩V)=ℝ $?

Comment: What does $(U \cap V)$ 'look like'? Note that it is $S^2$ with two points removes. If you remove one point, you have $S^2 - {pt}$ which by stereographic projection is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now if I remove one more point, say the origin, I have $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)]|$, i.e. the punctured plane. Maybe you know that the form $d\theta = \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2} dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy$ generates the 1st cohomology of the punctured plane. In which case we get $H_{dR}^1(U\cap V) = \mathbb{R}$.